# erlang mime get To field

Tags: parsing, erlang, mime

I try to get TO: user@mail.com field from mime mail message.

I have code:

```
parse_to(Data) ->
    List = string:tokens(Data, ":"),
    Sep1 = lists:map(fun(H) ->string:tokens(H, ":") end, List),
    io:format(Sep1),
    Sep2 = lists:filter(fun ([K | _]) -> K == "To" end, Sep1),
    ListAddress = lists:append(Sep2),
    [_ | Tail] = ListAddress,
    lists:map(fun(Address) -> string:tokens(Address, ",") end, Tail).
```

If i have short message for example: https://gist.github.com/865910 
I got in `io:format(Sep1)` https://gist.github.com/865905, it's ok all without **:**

But if i have long message with attachment: - https://gist.github.com/865914
I got in `io:format(Sep1)` - https://gist.github.com/865906 everything remains the same as it was with **:**

What's wrong? Why shot message normal parse and big message not parsed?

When i try use regexp:

```
List = binary_to_list(Binary),
re:run(List, "^To: (.)*$", [multiline, {capture, all_but_first, list}]).
```

I get only `{match, ["m"]}`

Why?

Thank you.

Comment: You have to use the parenthesis on the outside of dot-star `(.*)`, otherwise you'll only match the first character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a regular expression:

```
1> Data = <<"...">> % Your long message
<<"...">>
2> re:run(Data, <<"^To: (.*)$">>, [multiline, {capture, all_but_first, binary}]).
{match,[<<"shk@shk.dyndns-mail.com">>]}
```